# Installing XP on latest MacBook OS X

Tags: bootcamp, vmware, windows

My MacBook (purchased in 2007) with Windows XP installed through VMware software. I have some important software that works only in XP. My MacBook broke down and I purchased latest MacBook Pro (2015).

I am not able to install Windows XP because the Mac does not allow installation through USB or CD drive. Also OS X help seems to suggest that it won't support XP in Boot camp. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: You cannot install Windows XP natively on a 2015 MacBook Pro.  You can however install it in a virtual machine using VMware Fusion or other type 2 Hypervisor.  You'll have to make an ISO image of the Windows XP CD and install it using the ISO Image.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you just need to install *VMware Fusion* first, which will allow you to install and run Windows XP as a virtual machine, so that you can install and work with that important software of yours.

If you still have a backup copy of your old XP virtual machine (it's a large single file, if I remember correctly), you should be able to run that. Again,  after you have installed VMware Fusion.

Installing Windows using BootCamp is a very different thing (dual booting) and is indeed not supported for XP anymore.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. The situation is, I have reinstalled VMware fusion (professional version 5.05) and not able to install XP. Mac does not seen to read usb or cd drive and I get error message "Could not open /dev/vmmon: No such file or directory. Please make sure that the kernal module 'vmmon' is loaded"

Comment: @Param VMware Fusion 5 is not supported beyond OS X Mountain Lion and VMware Fusion 8 is the only version officially supported on OS X El Capitan.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will update to VMware 8 and see it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Veertu](http://veertu.com) from Mac Appstore to install Windows XP on your Mac. The app is free for open-source OS usage within their curated catalog and a paid upgrade to run arbitrary OS or Windows from ISO/DVD/CD installers.